# How to propagation context with trace-id in CommandLineRunner with spring boot 3 and micrometer?

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer-tracing

After migration to spring boot 3 and micrometer tracing library. The tracing IDs aren't automatically appended to the logs for Classes which implement the CommandLineRunner interface unlike for rest controllers.

Example code

```
public class JobRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final petsJobExecutor petsJobExecutor;

    @TrackExecutionTime
    public void run(String... args) {
        log.info("Started the job");
        petsJobExecutor.updatePets();
        log.info("Finished the job");
    }
}
```

How can I enable automatically trace-id context propagation for CommandLineRunner implementations in sprint boot 3 with micrometer?

Comment: Before anyone wastes time trying to answer this, please note that it has also been raised [on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34449) and [Gitter](https://matrix.to/#/!poRJqCihtKxXkqtIDZ:gitter.im/$aEg6ka9xSGdHKKjCAd9s8cQIVR27vNOpeae2zQ4HI2U?via=gitter.im&via=matrix.org&via=hive-mind.network).

Comment: Solved by using   Observation.createNotStarted("pets-job", observationRegistry).observe(() -> {
            log.info("Started the job");
            petsJobExecutor.updatePets();
            log.info("Finished the job");
        });